# SQL query to compute total number of customers who purchase >4 products on one day

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to write a SQL query to compute which customers have purchased more than 4 products on the same day.

Here are my tables:

Sales
    (`date`, `customer_id`, `product_id`, `units_sold`)

Products
    (`id`, `name`, `price`)

Customers
    (`id`, `name`)

& here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.product_id) as total_customers
FROM Sales s1
WHERE DATEDIFF(s1.date, s2.date)=0
INNER JOIN Sales s2
  ON s1.product_id = s2.product_id
HAVING COUNT(s.product_id) > 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the customers who have purchased more than 4 products on the same date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.customer_id
FROM Sales s
GROUP BY s.customer_id, date(s.date)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4;
```

This is one of the few cases where `SELECT DISTINCT` is used with `GROUP BY`.  If you want to know the dates as well, then include `date(s.date)` in the `SELECT`.

Note that this assumes that any given product is purchased by a customer only once on each date.  If a customer can have multiple records for a single product on one date, use `COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

To get the total number of *customers*, use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT s.customer_id
      FROM Sales s
      GROUP BY s.customer_id, date(s.date)
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
     ) c
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many mistakes's in your query try this

```
SELECT customer_id,cast(s1.date as date),COUNT(s1.product_id) as total_customers
FROM Sales s1
Group by customer_id,cast(s1.date as date)
HAVING COUNT(s1.product_id) > 4;
```

Comment: I got the following error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON s1.product_id = s2.product_id'"

Comment: there are no errors but no columns are being displayed

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected result

Comment: It works. Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3942/1) how do I get it to just display 2 for the number of customers who meet the specifications?